# how to open a specific form for each row in datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview

I made a form for projects and I need to post for each project row some tasks.
I made the form of project and the form of tasks with their classes in c# but I want help in making a relation between them to make the project form open a task form for each record through a link column.

```
   private void Populateusers()
    {

        List<Task> users = Task.LoadTasks();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = users;
        dataGridView1.Refresh();


    }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. In the meantime you can provide us with some code showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: Are you using HTMl for UI? If so, please provide us the code.

Comment: I am using Visual studio for UI using C# windows form application

Answer (score 0):

ok for that you can use like `ActionLink` method with use of appropriate java script

so that on click this link will show a specific form according to your requirement.....

here is a demo  ............................

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { @Id = p.Id }, new { @class = "operator-edit" })
```

for that java script is here

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".operator-edit").unbind("click").bind("click", function (e) {
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        jQuery.Ajax({
            url: url
            , dialog: { title: "Telephone edit" }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand the question,but I think what you're saying is,basically,you need to execute a different action on each row of the DataGridView by a LinkColumn,is that it?

Ok,you can catch the link click on the event "CellContentClick" of the DGV and depending on the value (`myDataGrdiView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value`) you open/execute the code you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [DataGridViewLinkColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewlinkcolumn.aspx) to add links in your grid.

If this is not what you need, please explain your issue in details.